# Vue cli problem with routing and getting files

Tags: vue-router, vue-cli

I release a project with VUE CLI.

Whene i build my project it's didn't work and **i know the problem**.

Javascript files in /js/* are not working because they are routing with vue it self, and instead of uploading javascript files, server return html files and i have the error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I found a solution to put all ressources (js, css, fonts) in external directory and edit index.html

**Question** how to fix this problem inside vue cli ?

**Example:** instead of getting the script in `mywebsite/js/app.a5fe57de.js` i get a page html in this url.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems a bit unclear, can you tell process to reproduce it?

Comment: @SwapnilSoni, i put an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem come from `.htaccess` file (i work with php in back end) given [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**To solve the problem** we should put all assets (javascripts/imgs/css ...) in a directory and turn off `Rewrite mod` in this folder.

**1.** create the file `vue.config.js` with the configurations :

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: "/",
    outputDir: "dist/",
    assetsDir: "public/assets/"
}
```

**2.** After the build of the project by the command `npm run build`, our assets  (javascripts/img/css ....) are in the directory `public`, then we put this `.htaccess` file inside it :

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

And the build project will work fine !